# Angular 2 and systemjs doesn't load

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, systemjs

I'm very new to web programming. Trying to go through examples from the "Mean Web Development" second edition book. It went okey until Angular was introduced. 
I'm trying to run an example from Chapter 7 of this book and the only thing I see in the browser is "Loading..." 
I can see it complains about:

[image]

Here is index.ejs file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title><%= title %></title>
 <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
 <mean-app>
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
 </mean-app>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.user = <%- user || 'null' %>;
 </script>

 <script src="lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>


  <script src="./systemjs.config.js"></script>

 <script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err)
  { console.error(err); });
 </script>


</body>
</html>
```

and systemjs.config.js file:

```js
(function(global) {
  var packages = {
    app: {
      main: './bootstrap.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  };

  var map = {
    '@angular': 'lib/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs'
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'router',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
  ];

  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] =
    { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

System.config({
  defaultJSExtension: true,
  transpiler: null,
  packages: packages,
  map: map
});
})(this);
```

Here is package.json:

```html
{
 "name": "MEAN",
 "version": "0.0.7",
 "scripts": {
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
  "app": "node server",
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run app\" ",
  "postinstall": "typings install"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
  "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
  "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
  "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
  "@angular/router": "3.1.1",
  "body-parser": "1.15.2",
  "core-js": "2.4.1",
  "compression": "1.6.0",
  "connect-flash": "0.1.1",
  "ejs": "2.5.2",
  "express": "4.14.0",
  "express-session": "1.14.1",
  "method-override": "2.3.6",
  "mongoose": "4.6.5",
  "morgan": "1.7.0",
  "passport": "0.3.2",
  "passport-facebook": "2.1.1",
  "passport-google-oauth": "1.0.0",
  "passport-local": "1.0.0",
  "passport-twitter": "1.0.4",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
  "systemjs": "0.19.39",
  "zone.js": "0.6.26"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "3.1.0",
  "traceur": "0.0.111",
  "typescript": "2.0.3",
  "typings": "1.4.0"
 }
}
```

and tsconfig.json:

```html
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "system",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false
 },
 "exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "typings/main",
  "typings/main.d.ts"
 ]
}
```

typings.json:

```html
{
 "globalDependencies": {
  "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160914114559",
  "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.5.0+20161025102649",
  "socket.io-client":
  "registry:dt/socket.io-client#1.4.4+20160317120654",
  "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20161102143327"
 }
}
```

I tried to change systemjs to webpack, but everything became even more confusing...

What would be the steps I need to take to resolve this issue?

Comment: Webpack and SystemJS are different approaches to packaging, and switching from one to the other is not trivial.  What you want to do is switch back to SystemJS, open up developer tools in your browser, look at the error you're getting, then come back and update your question. Nothing looks inherently wrong with your setup, assuming all the files and libraries are there. Did you just forget to do an npm install to install the various packages?

Comment: I did npm install, without it it wouldn't even run and in this case it runs, but doesn't load. The code is straight from the book. The only error message I see is the one I posted in the original question and this error pops up at the end of the System.import statement.

Comment: Sorry I missed the original error message. Is a line number given or any other information?  I'd guess you have an extra `<` somewhere.

Comment: The above error shows up at the end of this line: System.import('app').catch(function(err)
  { console.error(err); });

Comment: Is there a stack trace or other line information?  Can you share you package.json and/or directory structure?

Comment: Hi Jeffry, please see above - updated my question with the additional information - I can't really get a stack trace, it is running, doesn't break, sorry as I've mentioned I don't know much about web development...

Comment: Nothing is obvious to me what the problem is.  I'm guessing at this point, but maybe try to remove the comma after `platform-browser-dynamic` in the systemjs.config.js file?

Comment: tried it... didn't work... switched to webpack. thanks!